# In-App purchases Apple ID vs server's user

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, webserver, mkstorekit

I'm trying to implement a multi-platform app with in-app purchases. I'm using MKStoreKit and non-consumable content. I would use user registration in the server side. The app could be used without registering any user, so it would be possible to download content without being registered.

The problem comes because I'm not handling the purchases, but Apple (using Apple ID).

- If I buy one content with userA, then log in as userB and try to buy the same content, an alert pops up saying something like "You've already purchased this In App Purchase but it hasn't been downloaded.", how can I handle this?
- If I purchase some content without being registered and then register a user, how can I sent my purchases and bind them with this user only?
- If I buy some content with userA and then change my Apple ID, I won't own that content anymore according to my Apple ID, how can I handle this kind of situations?

It seems a little messy to deal with Apple IDs, registered and non-registered users... It would be easier to buy consumable coins, but I'm afraid of Apple's rejection.

I'm really struggled with this...

Thanks for any help.